# Multiple tinymce textareas on one page -- correct chrome menu not always appearing

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have a page with multiple tinymce textareas, using the browser's default context menu. The issue I'm having is that sometimes Chrome will show the correct textarea context menu (cut, copy, paste, etc.), but every second time I open the context menu (roughly), it shows the non-textarea content menu (back, forward, reload, etc.)

I've a sample Fiddle here demonstrating the issue: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Bugaab

If you right click in either text area (in Chrome) a few times, in different locations, the different menus will appear.

I'm fairly sure I'm initializing the controls correctly. The problem doesn't occur with only a single textarea.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I can only see the default chrome context menu...

Comment: Right clicking in different parts of the text area does show both of these two menus at different times: https://i.imgur.com/osLhFOg.png, https://i.imgur.com/1KP2hay.png

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean... I see the paste and paste as plain text only if I right click on the row that has the caret, might be as designed?

Comment: No, it's definitely not as designed, as it works correctly with only a single textarea.

Comment: Let's see if I can explain what I am seeing: If I right click in any of the editors on the line that has the caret I get the tinyMCE context menu. If I right click in any other place I get the chrome context menu. This happens in both editors, that's why I wonder if it works as designed.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. It's not a tinymce context menu at all. That's Chrome's context menu when it opens inside an input or textarea. It has different menu items depending on the context.

I said earlier that the issue didn't occur when only a single tinymce textarea was on page, but I see now this was incorrect. The issue happens for every tinymce textarea.

I think the problem is to do with the area of the textarea. Tinymce hides the actual native textarea control and draws its own, and it’s probably incorrectly mapping the dimensions somehow, confusing Chrome into thinking the mouse click is outside the control.

From what I’ve seen, the norm with this control is to use its own context menu rather than rely on the browsers, which is probably why I’ve had such difficulty finding mentions of the Chrome problem anywhere.

Comment: To be more precise TinyMCE creates a series of `div`s for the menus/toolbars and the content area is actually an `iFrame`.  You are correct that when TinyMCE appears on the page the original `textarea` is no longer visible nor can you interact with it via keyboard or mouse.